# Not sure where to ask, which 1 is actually better?

Tags: c#

```
       Customer cust = new Customer();
       cust.RecId = lblRecId.Text;
       cust.CustCd = txtCustCd.Text;
       cust.CustName = txtCustName.Text;
       cust.Save();
```

OR

```
cust.SaveRecord(lblRecId.Text , txtCustCd.Text, txtCustName.Text)
```

both doing the same job, but which 1 is actually better? I and lead actually have an argue on this, I using the top method, as I can freely assign the value in any order, but he insist that the bottom 1 is better? no idea what actually to search, any 1 mind to give me some guideline on this

Comment: First one is better because it can expand to include newer properties if your customer class changes

Comment: bottom seems better as the code compatibility is considered there... up to my knowledge

Comment: Define "better". For what? Readability? Maintainability? Lines of Code? Performance? Memory usage? Something else?

Comment: They both have their own merits. Voting to close as it will cause debate.

Comment: I'm sorry if it really will cause debate, I feel the bottom method will need to keep on passing the parameter if there is new value to be pass in, and if another method getting the same parameter, I need to refill in the parameter, using the top properties, I just need to add in the properties, and can be use for any method in the class?

Comment: That's doesn't really clarify the question. What exactly is the issue? And please update the question instead of putting important information in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is much better approach. but it's a personal view.

`Save` should persist the current state of object. and state can be updated in other parts of program.

However having an overload `Save` is also not bad idea. but as the no. of fields increase the latter version becomes bulky and un-maintainable.

Comment: So, you are saying you really should be voting to close as not-constructive?

Comment: yes, agree that it's not-constructive. but still deserves an answer. again personal view. :)

Comment: Any link to get more info about this two? I don't wish to make it as debate, I just wanna to gain more knowledge, so I can study between these, sorry for the waste

Comment: There are many questions that deserve answers, but that do not belong on Stack Overflow. Not constructive questions are such.

Comment: Language specification don't provide a concrete answer for it. they just recommend the way. it depends on the project convetions followed within team. with experience and based on circumstances you'll have have to use both ways in future. so it depends.

Comment: @Oded: it may create a debate but it's still a valid question. regarding coding convetions, mostly the debate ends successfully with a proper result.

Comment: And yet, our FAQ specifically mentions that questions that foster debate shouldn't be asked. Which is why this question currently has 3 close votes and will probably end up closed and deleted. It does not belong here. Stack Overflow is not a forum for debating things on. This has been discussed extensively on meta.

Comment: Where actually to ask this question? any keyword that I can actually search for? As I wanna know the advantage and disadvantage for both of this method

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is great if you already have all the data for a customer in a customer class.
If you do not have a customer class with data the second approach is better.

We often use the first approach, but then we also have some static methods to retrieve the customer with a specific key e.g.:

```
 // A static method in Customer class.
 public static Customer Get(string key)
 {
     Customer customer;
     FCustomers.TryGetValue(key, out customer);
     return customer;
 }
```

This comes with a static constructor that loads all customers into memory and methods to Create, Save and Delete customers from database as well.

This is ofcause only relevant for data that is needed all the time, I don't think that customer is that kind of data.